# How do I enable Kerberos for the mount command in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, virtual-machine, kerberos, mount

Can someone tell me how to make `mount` recognize `-o sec=krb5` as a valid option in a docker container or dockerfile?

Does Ubuntu 16.04 require a reboot for `mount` to understand Kerberos?
There doesn't appear to be any information on this online. I only find articles about Red Hat which aren't helpful.

Below is the dockerfile I’ve been using to try and figure it out.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ADD krb5.conf krb5.keytab /etc/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y krb5-user nfs-common
```

I launch the new image in a container using the following.

`sudo docker run --name test_krb --privileged -it test_krb /bin/bash`

Inside the container, I can use `kinit` without any issues, so I know Kerberos is working. However, `mount` doesn't understand it for some reason.

Below is the mount command I’ve been running inside of the container along with the output.

```
$ mount -vo sec=krb5,port=2050 <hostname>:/ /mnt/nfs
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Sep 20 04:06:45 2018
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,port=2050,vers=4,addr=X.X.X.X,clientaddr=X.X.X.X'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

I’ve tried this in a VM running the same commands and it failed as well until I rebooted the VM. A reboot appears to be necessary to make this work, but I’m not sure how to accomplish this in a container/dockerfile.

Thanks